# How to add a 'gift basket' option during checkout?

Tags: gift-wrap

```
Magento 1.9.4
Porto theme
```

We would like to offer our customers 2 options somewhere during check-out:

1. Option #1: deliver normal @ no additional charge
2. Option #2: deliver as gift basket for an additional charge of $30

*What would be the easiest way to do that?*

Comment: in my opinion, the best way to create a custom shipping option